# Terminology in interval estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, terminology, credible-interval, fiducial

**(1)** Confidence intervals
**(2)** Posterior probability intervals
**(3)** Fiducial intervals
Is there some conventional term that encompasses these three sorts of intervals, but does not include prediction intervals? All of them are BLANK intervals. Fill in the blank.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to my mind are [**interval estimates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_estimation), but this seems to be broader then you are asking.

Comment: It's not broader than what I was asking, but I wondered if some adjective followed by "intervals" could do it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am not aware of anything like this.